# Ubuntu 14.04 as a Gateway / Router and a Firewall

Tags: 14.04, router, gateway

My current system setup is Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64 Bit,and I am using Internet from a router using a public IP

```
eth0 - WAN Public IP 182.x.x.x  
eth1 - LAN private IP 192.168.0.1
```

Now I want to distribute this connection to other computers using my system as a `Gateway`, My system IP is `192.168.0.1` and other computers on the network are using  static IP `192.168.0.2` and  `192.168.0.255`  as `static` and/or `DHCP`.

Also I want to setup a firewall on my system so that I can monitor and control traffic of other system's on the network.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Open a Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Enter following command to edit `interfaces` file:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
3. Edit the file with the following lines: 
   (add your `netmask` and `gateway`)

   ```
   auto lo 
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 182.x.x.x 
   netmask  x.x.x.x 
   gateway x.x.x.x

   auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet static 
   address 192.168.0.1
   netmask x.x.x.x
   ```
4. Now edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment:

   ```
   # net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

   so that it reads:

   ```
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

   and save it by entering

   `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`
5. To enable IP masquerading, enter following set of commands in terminal:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
   ```

Update: Fix strange "-–state" causing command to fail and fix nat MASQUERADE to eth0 (wan interface)

Comment: done everything as adviced... but if i edit /etc/network/interfaces and restart service it connect automatically to eth1 and will not to Internet via eth0. If I edit connectio using GUI mode it connect to the internet using eth0. Now the problem is that I am not able to connect my client computer using IP 192.168.0.5/nm.255.255.255.0/gw.192.168.0.1 to internet.  any suggestion?

Comment: I want to add that after you change the line ``net.ipv4.ip forward=1``, you want to run ``sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`` to make the new value take effect.

Comment: You still have the devices swapped in the last two lines in step 5, and you don't have any mention of default security (i.e., forward should have a DROP policy).

Answer (score 4):

@chreekat's comment is correct that the Ethernet adapters are swapped in step 5 of @Anbu's answer, and as shown (as of 2017-02-21) creates A HUGE SECURITY HOLE that permits unrestricted access to the private network by anyone on the public network.

The corrected configuration for step 5 is shown below.

Theory of operation: (Rule #2) Packets ingressing from the public network (eth0) are accepted for forwarding out to the private network (eth1) if and only if the ingressing public packet is related to a conversation that was established by a host on the private network. (Rule #3) Accept all packets ingressing from the private network (eth1) and forward them out to the public network (eth0).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use, works well always.
A combination of various tutorials.
Tested on Ubuntu 16.04LTS too.

**Step A-- Make sure that ufw is installed**

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

**Step B -- Configure your network interfaces**.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Configure the *interfaces* file to be something like this below:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The WAN primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
        address 182.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

#LAN side interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        address 192.168.0.1
```

Save the file by selecting CTRL-X from nano or any other editor you prefer.

**Step C -- Allow IP Forward**.
Set the forwarding.
Edit the file */etc/sysctl.conf*

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Remove the comment on this line `# net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` for it to be `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
Save changes and move to next step.

**Step D -- Masquerading/forwarding rules**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Persist *iptables* changes

```
sudo su
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
sudo nano /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

Enter this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

Save changes
Then edit/create next iptables file

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptables
```

Enter this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.rules ]; then
    iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
fi
exit 0
```

Save changes.
Make both files executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptables
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

**Step E -- Finalize with ufw configuration**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/ufw
```

Change parameter forward policy to accept

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

Save changes.

I have my SSH on port 49870, so I also allowed *ufw* to accept connections on that port:

```
sudo ufw allow 49870
```

**Step F -- Do not forget to enable ufw**.

```
sudo ufw enable
```

At this stage, just reboot your system.
Then all LAN devices can use it as main gateway.
On a side note, *ufw* is very convenient to manage firewall settings.

Comment: This also worked for me. Strangely, the crucial part was enabling ufw on Ubuntu 20.04 to get the basic functionality working. I'd assume that without ufw enabled, the setup would work. Does enabling ufw disable some other ubuntu iptable rules that conflict with steps C and D?