# Ubuntu Server 17.04 reachable via LAN, but not via WAN interface

Tags: networking, server

I am having network troubles on my relatively new Ubuntu Server 17.04 installation. The computer has two network ports (on the motherboard): one connected to a modem which gives WAN IPs and one connected to a router which gives LAN IPs.

The problem is that both interfaces get an IP, but the computer is only pingable/reachable via SSH from the LAN interface. Pinging the WAN IP gives timeouts. I would like to get the WAN interface working to use the computer as a router in the end.

What I tried:

- Switching to systemd-networkd, which seemed to solve the problem
  temporarily, but then it started giving self-assigned IPs to the
  interfaces. I reverted to using the basic /etc/network, and now I
  have IPs and no WAN connectivity. I have internet connectivity, but
  this seems to go via the LAN interface.
- Disabling the firewall (sudo ufw disable), having no effect
- Rebooting and ifdown/ifup the interface multiple times
- Disabling IPv6

**EDIT:**

I now notice a lot of DHCPREQUEST messages in my syslog, which might have something to do with the problem:

```
Aug 31 11:40:22 home dhclient[1450]: DHCPREQUEST of xx.xxx.13.139 on enp3s0 to xxx.xxx.132.120 port 67 (xid=0x1b73764)
Aug 31 11:47:31 home dhclient[1450]: message repeated 29 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of xx.xxx.13.139 on enp3s0 to xxx.xxx.132.120 port 67 (xid=0x1b73764)]
Aug 31 11:47:47 home dhclient[1450]: DHCPREQUEST of xx.xxx.13.139 on enp3s0 to xxx.xxx.132.120 port 67 (xid=0x1b73764)
```

ifconfig:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xxx.13.139  netmask 255.255.224.0  broadcast xx.xxx.31.255
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16438  bytes 988374 (988.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52  bytes 7615 (7.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 518  bytes 50724 (50.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 116  bytes 15468 (15.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2  bytes 100 (100.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 100 (100.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp4s0
xx.xxx.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WAN
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp

# LAN
allow-hotplug enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: I think your server needs a routing through these network interfaces. You should review iptables configuration. Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590920/ubuntu-14-04-as-a-gateway-router-and-a-firewall

Comment: Thanks, I did this, but no change... Anyway, I think the WAN interface should be pingable before any configuration as router, no?